# 2 value in one variable (const and const_cast) c++

Tags: c++, constants, const-cast

```
void main() {

const int a = 10;
const int *b = &a;
int *c = const_cast <int*>(b);
*c = 5;
cout<<a<<" "<<*b<<" "<<*c<<endl; //10 5 5
cout<<&a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<endl; //same address
cout<<*(int*)&a<<" "<<*&a<<endl; //5 10
}
```

what makes type cast affected this?
where is the value stored?

Comment: It's `int main`, not `void main`. And modifying constant data is undefined behaviour. Don't expect anything.

Comment: `const_cast` should only be used (never, heh) when you *know* the referenced data was not `const`. I.e. if `a` were **not** `const`, then `const_cast`ing the `b` pointer has merit. As written you're violating that. [See it live](http://ideone.com/cutUWq)

Comment: Your question isn't clear so it's hard to know exactly what information your looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior: with the `const_cast<int*>(b)` you remove the `const` qualifier from an object which actually is `const` and the assignment to that object may have arbitrary effect.

The observed effects indicate that the implementation replaced uses of `a` with its immutable value while it dereferences `b` to determine the value. It could have arbitrary other effect, too, though. For example, a segmentation fault when trying to write a write protected location could be a possible outcome. Well, anything can happen.